# New dialog activity not starting in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity, that starts the Dialog box when the list item is long pressed. I start the activity via this code snippet:

```
private void showWifiSettings(int arg2) {
                Intent newIntent = new Intent("com.example.searchingwifi.DIALOGACTIVITY");
                startActivity(newIntent);
                }
```

And, the code in the new Dialog activity is as undersigned.

```
package com.example.searchingwifi;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;

public class DialogActivity extends DialogFragment{


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null));


        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

On long pressing the corresponding list item, the Logcat gives me the following error, and the application stops running.

```
06-27 12:54:22.150: E/AndroidRuntime(25118): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-27 12:54:22.150: E/AndroidRuntime(25118): Process: com.example.searchingwifi, PID: 25118
06-27 12:54:22.150: E/AndroidRuntime(25118): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.searchingwifi/com.example.searchingwifi.DialogActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.searchingwifi.DialogActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
06-27 12:54:22.150: E/AndroidRuntime(25118):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
06-27 12:54:22.150: E/AndroidRuntime(25118):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-27 12:54:22.150: E/AndroidRuntime(25118):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-27 12:54:22.150: E/AndroidRuntime(25118):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-27 12:54:22.150: E/AndroidRuntime(25118):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-27 12:54:22.150: E/AndroidRuntime(25118):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-27 12:54:22.150: E/AndroidRuntime(25118):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-27 12:54:22.150: E/AndroidRuntime(25118):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-27 12:54:22.150: E/AndroidRuntime(25118):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-27 12:54:22.150: E/AndroidRuntime(25118):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-27 12:54:22.150: E/AndroidRuntime(25118):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-27 12:54:22.150: E/AndroidRuntime(25118):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-27 12:54:22.150: E/AndroidRuntime(25118): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.searchingwifi.DialogActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
06-27 12:54:22.150: E/AndroidRuntime(25118):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
06-27 12:54:22.150: E/AndroidRuntime(25118):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
06-27 12:54:22.150: E/AndroidRuntime(25118):    ... 11 more
```

Can anyone help me with the error, and where am I making the mistake ?

EDIT :-
Even if simply starting a new Dialog Activity, the system is still giving the error. The LogCat is as given below.

```
06-30 03:54:10.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1175): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-30 03:54:10.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1175): Process: com.example.testingdialog, PID: 1175
06-30 03:54:10.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1175): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testingdialog/com.example.testingdialog.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.testingdialog.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
06-30 03:54:10.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
06-30 03:54:10.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-30 03:54:10.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-30 03:54:10.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1175):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-30 03:54:10.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1175):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-30 03:54:10.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1175):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-30 03:54:10.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-30 03:54:10.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1175):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-30 03:54:10.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1175):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-30 03:54:10.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1175):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-30 03:54:10.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1175):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-30 03:54:10.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1175):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-30 03:54:10.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1175): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.testingdialog.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
06-30 03:54:10.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1175):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
06-30 03:54:10.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1175):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
06-30 03:54:10.550: E/AndroidRuntime(1175):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: try to have DialogActivity extend activity and use a dialog theme on this activity

Comment: I have added the Dialog theme to it. And as per the developers page, even extending `DialogFragment` does not make much difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to start activity which is actually `DialogFragment`. Either make it as `DialogActivity` and start as activity like this:

```
Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DialogActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

**OR**

You can keep it as `Dialogragment` only, and show as dialogfragment instead of starting a new activity.

Example:

```
MyDialogFragment myDialogFragment = new MyDialogFragment();
myDialogFragment.show(fragManager, "myDialogFragment");
```

Reference Links:

[Dialog Fragment example](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/05/using-dialogfragments.html)

[Dialog Activity example](http://www.javabeat.net/dialog-activity-android/)

Comment: None of the suggested link methods actually working. @PurpleDroid - The application stops as soon as the item in the list is long pressed. Can you suggest an alternative way?

Answer (score 0):

You should check this:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ShowingADialog

A dialog isn't the same as an Activity.

Currently you must have

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
...
```

change this to

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{
...
```

Then for showing your Dialog add this code in your FragmentActivity

```
public void showDialog() {
DialogActivity newDialog = new DialogActivity();
newDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "myDialog");
```

}

Tip: Do not call your custom Dialog class like DialogActivity, but something like MyCustomDialog (not using "Activity" in the class name)

Comment: In the same, when `getSupportFragmentManager()` is used, it shows error as it says the method does not exist!

Comment: Change your Activity to FragmentActivity.

Comment: If It's not clear enough, tell me. I'll show it in more detail, of does it work right now?

Comment: I updated the name of my Dialog Activity to `MyCustomDialog` and then I am trying to do the same thing, as you told me. But, I still don't get, how will the Fragment Manager thing, search for, which Dialog Activity I am trying to start!

Answer (score 0):

Here you are opening DialogFragment. Please try with below code.

```
DialogFragment newFragment = new DialogActivity();
newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

Hope it will help

Updated:
Here you are setting LayoutInflator instead of view. That is why it is giving error of input argument. Try below:

```
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        // Get the layout inflater
        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
        builder.setView(view);

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Comment: No, the above snippet doesn't work, the `show` part shows error, giving that the input arguments are not the ones required for the method.

Comment: As per your instructions, I tried doing the above thing, in the DialogActivity, I changed the code in `OnCreateDialog` to the above given one. But how am I supposed to give the class name of the new Dialog Activity that I am building, as in what code goes into the main activity?